# How to delete a specific one-dimensional array from two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have project's function as follow:
I have a two-dimensional array, then should delete the specific one-dimensional array.
The two-dimensional array is:

//ID,Name,Age,Score.Student's ID is unique.

```
var arr1=[["1","aaa","20","90"],
      ["2","bbb","21","80"],
      ["3","ccc","22","70"], 
      ["4","ddd","23","60"],
     ];

var arr2=["3","ccc","22","70"];
```

I want to get the a two-dimensional array.The result as follow:

```
result=arr1=[["1","aaa","20","90"],
      ["2","bbb","21","80"],
      ["4","ddd","23","60"],
     ];
```

I write some codes,but I get a logic error.The URL of jsfiddle is:[Edit fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liminjun88/2pYT2/2/)

Thank you very much.

Comment: According to your demo, you are using Underscore, right?

Comment: Just a tip: if your ID is unique, use a dictionary/object: it will make much quicker to find/add/delete new items.

Comment: @MarcoCI My workmate also suggest me to use the object, then implement the add or delete methods for this object.I will try do this later.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Underscore in your demo:

```
var result = _.filter(arr1, function (el) {
    return el[0] != arr2[0];
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2pYT2/4/

Answer (score 2):

So you want to delete the array in `arr1` with the ID correspoding to the ID in `arr2`? If thats the problem simply write:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    if(arr1[i][0] === arr2[0])
        arr1.splice(i, 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2pYT2/3/

Comment: Actually in his answer he's comparing strings, not arrays

Comment: I'm not comparing arrays, I'm comparing strings i.e. elements from arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I misread that. That still seems wrong though, I think all of the elements in `arr1[i]` need to match `arr2` to remove it, but perhaps I've also misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function of Array. See the code below, not tested but hope it helps.

This is to fix your current code. Better is solution is to convert two dimensional array to dictionary as  MarcoCI suggested. It will help to you a lot.

```
var arr1 = [
    ["1", "aaa", "20", "90"],
    ["2", "bbb", "21", "80"],
    ["3", "ccc", "22", "70"],
    ["4", "ddd", "23", "60"], ];
var arr2 = ["3", "ccc", "22", "70"];




// filters comparing all elements
// use filterArray(sourceArray, array1, array2, array3 ...)
function filterArray(arr) {
    var args = arguments;
    return arr.filter(function (x) {
        for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            var tarr = args[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < tarr.length && j < x.length; j++) {
                if (tarr[j] != x[j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

}

console.log(filterArray(arr1, arr2));

// filters comparing 0th element
// use filterArrayID(sourceArray, array1, array2, array3 ...)
function filterArrayID(arr) {
    var args = arguments;
    return arr.filter(function (x) {
        for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            var tarr = args[i];
            if (tarr[0] != x[0]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

}

console.log(filterArrayID(arr1, arr2));
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2pYT2/5/